For a reduced abelian $p$-group $G$, does $P$ being finite imply $G$ is finite?
Let $G$ be a reduced abelian $p$-group, and let $P$ be the subgroup of elements of order $p$. If $P$ is finite, is $G$ necessarily also finite?
Recall that a group $G$ is said to be reduced if it contains no divisible subgroups. A group $G$ is said to be divisible if every element is divisible by $n$ for each natural number $n$.
This seems to be true in the case where the length of the group is at most $\omega$ (i.e. $G$ is a direct sum of cyclic groups), but I cannot find a proof of this fact without this restriction. Here is the proof in that case: in order for the group to be infinite, the group must contain either infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ for some $n$, in which case clearly $P$ is infinite, or it must contain copies of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ for arbitrarily high $n$, each copy introducing at least one new element of order $p$.

First of all, note that every $p$-group is divisible away from $p$, i.e. for any non-zero integer $n$ not divisible by $p$ and any $y \in G$, there exists $x \in G$ such that $nx = y$. Indeed, we can take $x$ to be a suitable power of $y$. Thus, $G$ being reduced is equivalent to no subgroup of $G$ is $p$-divisible (i.e. all elements are divisible by $p$).
What is the relevance of the finiteness of $P$? Well, let's say that for some $y \in G$, you are looking at the solutions to the equation $px = y$. If $x_1, x_2$ are two such solutions, then $p(x_1-x_2) = 0$, implying that the solution space, if not empty, is precisely a coset of $P$. By hypothesis, there are finitely many such solutions.
Now, construct the following rooted tree with nodes as elements of $G$:

The root node is the identity element of $G$.
For any non-identity node $x \in G$, the parent node is $px$.

We have already shown that any node has finitely many children, so at any fixed depth, there are only finitely many nodes. Do you see why the tree cannot have infinite depth? Can you conclude from here that $G$ must be a finite group?

Level 1 seems to be the elements of order $p$, level 2 of $p^2$, etc. Every group element is a node on the tree since it is a $p$-group, so if the tree does not have infinite depth, it is a finite tree and thus the group is finite. But I don't understand why the tree cannot have infinite depth. Can you say more about what you had in mind here? I know that in each subgroup of $G$ there is some node with no child since if a node has a child it is divisible by $p$. But I don't see why other nodes can't have enough children to give the tree infinite depth.

If the tree has infinite depth, then can you construct an ascending chain of cyclic groups whose union is a divisible group?

By depth do you mean the same thing as tree height?

Yes. I am using depth for height.

Yes, okay. If the tree is infinite, then since it is finitely branching there is a path through the tree by compactness. This is what gives rise to the aforesaid sequence of subgroups. I don't see what tree height in particular has to do with it, but I think this argument works. Thanks!
